# hpsa_allow_any=1 and centos7.5

Tags: centos, hp

I have the old HP server with Smart Array controller.
CentOS boots only with **hpsa_allow_any=1** option.

I type this string every time after server reboot. But I want to save this option forever, what's why I want to edit `modprobe.conf`. 
In old versions of CentOS, as I remember, `modprobe.conf` was in the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory. But now there is no such file after default installation of CentOS 7.5.

So I have two questions:

1. In what config file do I need to add this option?
2. What do I need to do after that (`/sbin/dracut -v --force` or something like that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can permanently add this to boot options by editing `/etc/default/grub` file. You have to add this at the end of line which starts from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`.

Then recreate grub config file using this command:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Regarding modprobe configuration: nothing changed. Configuration stil can be put in `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory. See `man 5 modprobe.d` for reference.

Comment: Hello. This is not a solution. And I don't know why. After editing grub file and recreating the grub, I do 'restart' and server boots to emergency console instead of normal linux terminal. So as I see, adding this string to grub file and recreating  is not enough. However, if I edit grub with 'e'-key after rebooting (I add hpsa_allow_any=1 in it), server boots correctly.

Comment: No, this is my mistake, i forgot about "hspsa." before "hpsa_allow_any=1"